# Before-save flow won't run on creation of a Task

Tags: visual-workflow

I've created a Flow, set it to execute on creation and update of a Task. It works great on update, but does not fire on insert.

[image: ow]

Wondering if this is a known issue, or perhaps I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: How are you creating the Task in your tests? Manually in the UI or through other automation?

Comment: Manually, sending an email to myself.

Comment: Wondering if since Tasks are polymorphous that it's possible that isn't determined until later in the creation process in this case? Is Activity an option instead?

Comment: It appears that AccountId is automatically filled based on WhoId or WhatId, but not until later in the order of execution than the before-save flow, maybe not until after save?

Comment: `AccountId` is definitely populated after the "before save"